# How to find an entry by property in kvs

Tags: erlang

How to find an entry by property or predicate function in kvs? For example:

```
kvs:find(fun(X) -> X#user.name == "Alexander").
```

I can use this:

```
lists:filter(Predicate, kvs:all(entity)).
```

But I don't want to load all entries into memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that kvs is key-value storage, so we have to search entry only by keys specified in the entity table schema:

```
-record(user, {
   id,
   userName,
   password
}).

#table{name=user,fields=record_info(fields,user), keys = [userName]}
```

Then we can do this:

```
kvs:index(user, userName, "Alexander").
```